# asp.net how to save parent-child (master-detail) record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, asp.net-2.0

Please guide me how to save Master-detail record in sql server database. All of my data is in a single form.

I am not getting how to pass detail records into stored procedure ? Is there any way other than Transation+ bulk insert ? It looks like complex.

thanks

Comment: I guess I didn't get the question. If you want to insert or update both master and child table, you can do this by writing a stored procedure and update/insert to both tables.

Comment: Thanks Pabuc, but issue is how to pass detail records data to stored procedure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help: [Passing a DataSet to a SQLCLR Stored Procedure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpapiez/archive/2005/09/26/474059.aspx)